# Using Swift to unescape unicode characters, ie \u1234

Tags: utf-8, swift

I have problems with special characters when using JSON in xcode 6 with swift

I found these codes in Cocoa/objective C to solve some problems converting accent but could not make it work in Swift. Any suggestions for how to use it? ... best alternative suggestions would also be cool ...

Thanks

```
NSString *input = @"\\u5404\\u500b\\u90fd";
NSString *convertedString = [input mutableCopy];

CFStringRef transform = CFSTR("Any-Hex/Java");
CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)convertedString, NULL, transform, YES);

NSLog(@"convertedString: %@", convertedString);
// prints: 各個都, tada!
```

Comment: Show the attempt you made to convert the code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's fairly similar in Swift, though you still need to use the Foundation string classes:

```
let transform = "Any-Hex/Java"
let input = "\\u5404\\u500b\\u90fd" as NSString
var convertedString = input.mutableCopy() as NSMutableString

CFStringTransform(convertedString, nil, transform as NSString, 1)

println("convertedString: \(convertedString)")
// convertedString: 各個都
```

(The last parameter threw me for a loop until I realized that `Boolean` in Swift is a type alias for UInt - YES in Objective-C becomes 1 in Swift for these types of methods.)

Comment: I have the same problem reading regular expressions from a plist file (the \ gets escaped resulting \\\). Using your solution I only get the changes when the value is printed to the console, but the variable as I see it in the debug remains the same. How do I get the characters unescaped to use in my code?

Answer (score 7):

Swift `String` extension:

```
extension String {
    var unescapingUnicodeCharacters: String {       
        let mutableString = NSMutableString(string: self)
        CFStringTransform(mutableString, nil, "Any-Hex/Java" as NSString, true)
        
        return mutableString as String
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3

```
let transform = "Any-Hex/Java"
let input = "\\u5404\\u500b\\u90fd" as NSString
var convertedString = input.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableString

CFStringTransform(convertedString, nil, transform as NSString, true)

print("convertedString: \(convertedString)")
// convertedString: 各個都
```