# Quickly unescape unicode characters in Swift

Tags: string, swift, unicode, swift2

How do you quickly unescape unicode characters in Swift Strings? Right now, I have an array of strings, and to make it somewhat more user-readable, I added the following code that loops through each String in the array

```
for i in 0...(titles.count - 1) {
    var s = titles[i]
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&quot;", withString: "\"")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&amp;", withString: "&")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\u00e1", withString: "\u{00e1}")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\u00e9", withString: "\u{00e9}")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\u00e8", withString: "\u{00e8}")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\u00e0", withString: "\u{00e0}")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\u00d8", withString: "\u{00d8}")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\u00c3", withString: "\u{00c3}")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\u00a4", withString: "\u{00a4}")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\u00eb", withString: "\u{00eb}")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\u2022", withString: "\u{2022}")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\u00c9", withString: "\u{00c9}")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\u00b3", withString: "\u{00b3}")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\u2019", withString: "\u{2019}")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\u2730", withString: "\u{2730}")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\u266b", withString: "\u{266b}")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\u00f8", withString: "\u{00f8}")
    s = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\/", withString: "/")
    titles[i] = s
}
```

For example, on the fifth line, any occurrence of `\u00e1` is replaced with the corresponding unicode character `á`.

The array of strings is generated using:

```
myHTMLString = try NSString(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Where `url = NSURL(string: "http://songa.nl/ajax.php?params=playlist/load/US87OmpN")!`

and splitting the string in different substrings, when an " is encountered.

Is there a less hack-y (and probably faster), and more generic way to unescape unicode characters?

Comment: What does "resolve" mean?

Comment: "resolve" would be automatically 'converting' the "\\uABCD" to "\u{ABCD}" in the Strings, thereby 'resolving' the unicode codes in each string to their appropriate characters.

Comment: Could you put your question in your question? State your goals clearly, precisely and concisely, and don't make people guess.

Comment: (I think the term you might be looking for is "unescape".)

Comment: The data from that URL is in JSON format. If you use the NSJSONSerialization class to convert the data into an object, all the "unescaping" is done automatically.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the comment from Kerrek, and searching for 'unescape' instead of 'resolve', the following lines resolved my problem:

```
let transform = "Any-Hex/Java"
let input = "\\u5404\\u500b\\u90fd" as NSString
var convertedString = input.mutableCopy() as NSMutableString

CFStringTransform(convertedString, nil, transform as NSString, 1)

println("convertedString: \(convertedString)")
// convertedString: 各個都
```

As seen from: [Using Swift to unescape unicode characters, ie \u1234](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318171/using-swift-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234)