# How to decode unicode characters in swift 3?

Tags: ios, unicode, utf-8, swift3, emoji

I am developing one chat application, for that everything is working fine except. This application is in both Android and iOS platform. We want to pass emoji in the chat. In android we use UTF encoding with `StringEscapeUtils`. it is working perfect in android. when we pass emoji [image] it is encoded and stored in DB like "\u263A".

Now in android this string is also decode and shown perfect in view but some how we can not decode the same string in iOS. We have simply try to 
decode using UTF string. But still it is not working.

I have already follow this link [Print unicode character from variable (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696142/print-unicode-character-from-variable-swift)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where you want to print on Label or textfield?

Comment: @SagarSnehi I want to set on both. but if solution get for textfield than also it will help me a lot.

Comment: @CrazyDeveloper probably it can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318171/using-swift-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234

Comment: if your unicode be like this than "\u{263A}" than this code will work on label labelName.text =  "\u{20B9}" without {} these brackets it will not take as a string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to use CFStringTransform like below.

```
let wI = NSMutableString( string: "\\u263a" )
CFStringTransform( wI, nil, "Any-Hex/Java" as NSString, true )
someUILabel.text = wI as String
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code work for me.

Comment: Awesome Solution :)

Comment: No help for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586825/swift-3-replace-or-format-unicode-characters-multiply-from-long-text

Answer (score 5):

You should try this:

For Example:

```
let charString = "263A"
    if let charCode = UInt32(charString, radix: 16),let unicode = UnicodeScalar(charCode)
    {
        let str = String(unicode)
        print(str)
    }
    else
    {
        print("invalid input")
    }
```

If you want to Print on Label/TextField then:

```
let charString = "263A"
if let charCode = UInt32(charString, radix: 16),let unicode = UnicodeScalar(charCode)
{
    let str = String(unicode)
    CharLabel.text = str             //Print on Label
    CharTextField.text = str         //Print on TextField
}
else
{
    print("invalid input")
}
```