# I need to remove this using encoding or decoding or replacement to remove \\U00b4 from string

Tags: swift

I am getting `I\\U00b4m` in place of `I'm`. How to decode or replace this `\\U00b4` from string ?

`I\\U00b4m looking for the only one man in my life.`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide more context and relevant code. How and where do you get this string from?

Comment: Looks like a [golden oldie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318171)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Swift to unescape unicode characters, ie \u1234](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318171/using-swift-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234)

Answer (score -3):

Easy way:

```
let aString = "This is my string"
let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\U00b4", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

More info in here: [Any way to replace characters on Swift String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string)

Comment: getting this error :- Invalid escape sequence in literal

Comment: If you are using swift3, check out the more info link please and follow the swift3 solution.

Comment: You should be flagging questions as duplicates rather than posting links to a different Stack Overflow post as an answer.

Comment: Thank you but im not sure this question is exact same of that link.