# How to parse uinicode json in swift 5

Tags: json, swift

I have received a json in swift. But when want to convert json response to array, it returns nil.My json contains Unicode  or Bengali or Arabic characters. 
Here is my json..

```
{
 "last_timestamp" = "2019-12-03 15:58:18";
 lat = "23.70899111111111";
 "location_name" = "Jagannath University (\U099c\U0997\U09a8\U09cd\U09a8\U09be\U09a5 \U09ac\U09bf\U09b6\U09cd\U09ac\U09ac\U09bf\U09a6\U09cd\U09af\U09be\U09b2\U09df), 10, Hindu Tample road (Shakhari Bazar), \U0995\U09c7\U09b0\U09be\U09a3\U09c0\U0997\U099e\U09cd\U099c \U0989\U09aa\U099c\U09c7\U09b2\U09be, \U09a2\U09be\U0995\U09be \U099c\U09c7\U09b2\U09be, \U09a2\U09be\U0995\U09be \U09ac\U09bf\U09ad\U09be\U0997, 1100, \U09ac\U09be\U0982\U09b2\U09be\U09a6\U09c7\U09b6";
 lon = "90.41054222222222"
}
```

I have tried to convert json like bellow which return nil

```
 let json = value as? [String: Any]
```

Please help me to parse the json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Swift to unescape unicode characters, ie \u1234](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318171/using-swift-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234)

Comment: have you tried with `as? NSDictionary`?

Comment: @AndresGomez I tried like  if let  json1 =  value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{}

Comment: check my answer pls

Comment: from the json that you post it has a wrong structure between each element of json we should have comma not semi colon

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you've posted is invalid. Please check the format, it *should* look like this:

```
{
 "last_timestamp": "2019-12-03 15:58:18",
 "lat": "23.70899111111111",
 "location_name": "Jagannath University ...",
 "lon": "90.41054222222222"
}
```

Given that, you can easily parse it like so:

```
struct Location: Codable {
    let lastTimestamp, lat, locationName, lon: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case lastTimestamp = "last_timestamp"
      case lat
      case locationName = "location_name"
      case lon
   }
}

do {
   let location = JSONDecoder().decode(Location.self, from: data)
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Comment: I have used alamofire like   AF.request(url,headers: headers).responseJSON  { response in} it response above like json

Comment: But when i called it in post man it return like {"lon": "90.38703111111111",
        "lat": "23.751273333333334",
        "speed": "16.0",
        "heading": 318,
        "distance": "",
        "device_id": "621f0bd7-5b6a-4807-bd5b-0c7836a1be73",
        "location_name": "Hamdard(waqf) Limited, Pantha Path, ধানমন্ডি আ/এ, লালমাটিয়া, ঢাকা, ঢাকা বিভাগ, বাংলাদ}